# Is there a short cut for going back to the beginning of a file by vi editor?

Tags: vi, shortcut

When reading a long file by vi editor, it would be very nice to get back to the beginning of the file by some short cuts when you really need to do so. Even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> sometimes is too slow. Does anyone know such a tool?

Answer (score 211):

After opening a file using vi

1) You can press  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>  to go the end of the file

and

2) **Press <kbd>g</kbd> twice to go to the beginning of the file**

**NOTE : -** g is case-sensitive (Thanks to @Ben for pointing it out)

Comment: gg does not exist in vi, only Vim.

Comment: `Shift` + `g` ---> Go to the bottom of the file.
`Shift` + `GG` ---> Go to the top of the file.

Comment: @Subhashree Pradhan - Thank you for the insights on Vi Vs Vim. However, looks like there is no such operator/command called 'Shift + GG' - I have just verified in both Vi and Vim. Otherwise, you can use 1G to go to the beginning of the file as the operator G takes a quantifier as a prefix.

Answer (score 82):

using `:<line number>` you can navigate to any line, thus `:1` takes you to the first line.

Answer (score 29):

### Go to the bottom of the file

- <kbd>G</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>

### Go to the top of the file

- <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

Answer (score 23):

Key in <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and it will take you to the beginning of the file. Converserly, <kbd>G</kbd> will take you to the end of the file.

Comment: Works fine in AIX

Comment: Works in OpenBSD

Comment: Works in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 18):

Well, you have `[[` and `]]` to go to the start and end of file. This works in vi.

Answer (score 15):

**To go end of the file:**
press <kbd>ESC</kbd>

1) type capital <kbd>G</kbd> (Capital G)

2) press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> (small g)

**To go top of the file there are the following ways:**
press <kbd>ESC</kbd>

1) press <kbd>1G</kbd> (Capital G)

2) press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> (small g) or <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

3) You can jump to the particular line number,e.g wanted to go 1 line number, press <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 12):

In command mode: <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>  will take you to first line

Comment: Very useful to go to any line in the file.

Answer (score 6):

Typing in `0%` takes you to the beginning.

`100%` takes you to the end.

`50%` takes you half way.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (start of file) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (end of file).

Works in both insert and nav modes.